# Adaptar imagen `backgroud-image` base64 a un `div`?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una imagen (puede variar sus dimensiones) en base 64 que tengo guardado en la base de datos, quiero adaptarla a un `div`, pero se recorta, como haría para que en caso de que se exceda ponga un `scroll`. ya puse el `overflow` en `css`, pero no me funciona ya que no es el contido que se desborda si no es el `background` del mismo `div`. Con el `img` no me sirve porque la idea es poner encima unas `divs` con unos botones.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach (var Casa in ViewBag.PlanoCasa)
        {
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#@Casa.Id">Casa@Casa.Id</a></li>
        }
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      @foreach (var Casa in ViewBag.Casa)
      {
        <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="@Casa.Id">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <div class="laclase" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,@Casa.Imagen)">
                <!--<img src="data:image/png;base64, @Casa.Imagen" />-->

            </div>
        </div>


      }

    </div>
```

Comment: Puedes probar a usar `max-height: 100px;` pero en pixeles. O puedes hacer `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: @LuisFernando Ya lo hice. e igual no me funciona

Comment: overflow:auto has probado?

Comment: Si. Tuve que optar por la etiqueta img poner absoluta la img, relative el div que la contiene y los divs ponerla en absolute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con esto la imagen deberia quedar ajustada al contenedor al que se lo apliques.

```
background-image: url("/imagen/rutaImagen");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

Con la propiedad `background-size:cover` como se ve en el enlace:
[Ejemplo de ajuste de imagen](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover)